# how i can delete all cache history in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import os
import inspect, sys
import time

from sys import platform
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import datetime
import random
from playsound import playsound
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)



driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
sleep(5)
"""
x = driver.find_element_by_id('dropdownMenu')
drop = Select(x)
drop.select_by_index(2)
time.sleep(4)
"""
clearButton = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-section > settings-privacy-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog').shadowRoot.querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataDialog').querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataConfirm')")
#click on the clear button now
clearButton.click()
```

**javascript error: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
the code is work great but in headless mode doesn't work i wonder how i can fix this problem?

**

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this, to run before your tests, and make sure the cache is cleared:

```
def clear_cache(driver, timeout=60):
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

    get_clear_browsing_button(driver).click()

    wait.until_not(get_clear_browsing_button)
```

Comment: It's not probleam about page loading wait. `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` is not opend at headless mode

Answer (score 0):

Use this argument: `--aggressive-cache-discard`

Comment: Reviewers: please consider whether adding `--aggressive-cache-discard` as an additional argument to OP's code might solve the problem before recommending deletion.